# .Net Core DI to filter class from startup

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

How do I inject the database to my TestAttribute class as .net core does magically to my controller.

```
    services.AddScoped<DbContextOptions>(p => p.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<Context>>());
    services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(Context), typeof(Context), ServiceLifetime.Transient));

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new TestAttribute(/*need parameter*/));
    }

    public HouseController([FromServices] Context database)
    {
        this.Database = database;
    }

    public class TestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public TestAttribute([FromServices] Context database)
        {
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that example from? `[FromService]` is not supposed to be used in controller constructor. It's there to inject a dependency into an action for example. And where is your `.AddDbContext<T>()` call?

Comment: Above my AddScoped. I Got: services.TryAddScoped(CreateContextOption). CreateContextOption returns a DbContextOptions that calls UseSqlServer(connectionString)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To inject dependencies into Filters you need to use the `ServiceFilter` attribute (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters))

Manually injecting it to an controller action

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(TestAttribute))]
public Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ...
}
```

Also your registration is wrong in the startup for all actions! `Filters.Add()` accepts a `Type`, when you want to use attributes which require dependencies (because you can't instantiate them in code), see ["Filter Scopes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) in the docs.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(TestAttribute));
}
```